# Как получить количество родительских элементов в JS?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли как-то получить количество родителей элемента (элемент - его родитель - родитель родителя) в JavaScript? Если да, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пройтись в цикле по всем родителям и посчитать.

Для получения родителя можно использовать [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

```js
function parentsCount(el) {
  if (!el) return 0;

  for (var i = 0; el.parentNode; i++, el = el.parentNode);

  return i;
}

console.log(parentsCount(nested))
```

```html
<div>2
  <div id="nested">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А не лучше выкинуть ошибку если `!el`, а не возвращать 0 незаметно?

Comment: Только document - это узел, а не элемент, поэтому число должно быть на 1 меньше, или нужно использовать parentElement.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, не понял сообщение. А все, увидел. В данном случае - не принципиально